# XSLT for-each problems

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for a way to output this code as html.

```
<legal>
  <heading>Poo</heading>
  <g>fart <a href="http://www.bclaws.ca/EPLibraries/bclaws_new/document/ID/freeside/96165_01">Freedom of Information and Protection of Privacy Act</a> (RSBC 1996 ch. 165):</g>
  <foo>
    <bar>a </bar>
    <bar>b </bar>
    <bar>c </bar>
    <bar>d </bar>
    <bar>e </bar>
    <bar>f </bar>
  </foo>
  <g> faf </g>
  <g> faf </g>
  <g> faf </g>
  <g> faf </g>
  <g> faf </g>
  <g> faf </g>
  <g> faf </g>
    <foo>
      <bar> a </bar>
      <bar> b </bar>
      <bar> c </bar>
    </foo>
  <g> asfd </g>
  <g> asfd </g>
  <g> asfd </g>
  <g> asfd </g>
  <g> asfd </g>
  <g> asfd </g>
  <g> asfd </g>
    <foo>
      <bar> a </bar>
      <bar> b </bar>
      <bar> c </bar>
    </foo>
</legal>
```

Here is my XSLT so far... I cannot seem to output each and every `g` element within the `p` tags... it only seems to output it once and never again. Also, I seem to only be outputting the same thing twice... Where am I going wrong?

```
<xsl:variable name="legal" select="document('legal.xml')/legal"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$legal/heading">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="$legal/heading"/></h3>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="$legal/g"/></p>
      <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="$legal/foo/bar">
          <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing the entire code fragment you've shown with this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('legal.xml')/legal" />
```

and adding these templates:

```
<xsl:template match="heading">
  <h3><xsl:apply-templates /></h3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="g">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
  <li><xsl:apply-templates /></li>
</xsl:template>
```

The reason you're getting duplicates at the moment is because you're iterating over each header, and then in each iteration of that loop, you're processing the same `g` element, and iterating over the same `foo` elements, regardless of which header they're after. In both your source and the html output, `g`/`p` elements are not children of `header`/`h3` elements, it doesn't make sense to treat them as such in your code.

Comment: Actually he's not iterating over all `g` elements... he's outputting the string value of the first `g` element (that's a child of `legal`). `value-of` only takes the first node in its select. Assuming XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Ah, true, but it's still iterating over all `foo`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
<xsl:variable name="legal" select="document('legal.xml')/legal"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$legal/heading">
<h3><xsl:value-of select="."/></h3>
<xsl:for-each select="../g"><p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p></xsl:for-each>
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$legal/foo/bar">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</xsl:for-each>
```